# PowerShell configuration with an rc-like file

Tags: powershell, windows-7, scripting

What script and where I should write in order to define:

1. `alias for ll="ls -l"`
2. `alias/function cd = "original cd; ll"`

So, my question has to parts where is the rc files of the Power Shell on Windows 7 and how to alias `ll` to `ls -l` and `cd` to `cd; ll`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a file in the place where the power shell points when you type `$profile` and press enter, if it does not exist. (For more info look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Also I have found a lots of good examples next to the `powershell.exe` in my system there is an example folder, where there is a file named `profile.ps1` with the following code:

```
set-alias cat        get-content
set-alias cd         set-location
set-alias clear      clear-host
set-alias cp         copy-item
set-alias h          get-history
set-alias history    get-history
set-alias kill       stop-process
set-alias lp         out-printer
set-alias ls         get-childitem
set-alias mount      new-mshdrive
set-alias mv         move-item
set-alias popd       pop-location
set-alias ps         get-process
set-alias pushd      push-location
set-alias pwd        get-location
set-alias r          invoke-history
set-alias rm         remove-item
set-alias rmdir      remove-item
set-alias echo       write-output

set-alias cls        clear-host
set-alias chdir      set-location
set-alias copy       copy-item
set-alias del        remove-item
set-alias dir        get-childitem
set-alias erase      remove-item
set-alias move       move-item
set-alias rd         remove-item
set-alias ren        rename-item
set-alias set        set-variable
set-alias type       get-content

function help
{
    get-help $args[0] | out-host -paging
}

function man
{
    get-help $args[0] | out-host -paging
}

function mkdir
{
    new-item -type directory -path $args
}

function md
{
    new-item -type directory -path $args
}

function prompt
{
    "PS " + $(get-location) + "> "
}

& {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 26; $i++) 
    { 
        $funcname = ([System.Char]($i+65)) + ':'
        $str = "function global:$funcname { set-location $funcname } " 
        invoke-expression $str 
    }
}
```

---

Also take into account the following problem. You may have the following error while executing the file located in `$profile`:

> "Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps" cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.

**Solution:** 
Check the current execution-policy

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-ExecutionPolicy
Restricted
PS C:\Windows\System32>
```

To change the execution policy to allow PowerShell to execute scripts from local files, run the following command:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Set-Executionpolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```